# Как в Visual Studio поменять иконку в своем приложении?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Вот к примеру если я создам консольный проект. Там изначально нет ни каких ресурсов. И я жму добавить ресурс, и выбираю иконку. ВСЕ! Она благополучно ставится при запуске и компиляции проекта.
А вот относительно не давно я начал изучать winapi. И там при создании проекта уже есть какие то ресурсы и по дефолту стоят иконки. Если я жму добавить и выбираю свою иконку, она добавляется но применяются все так же дефолтные иконки...

Answer (score -1):

Почитай про структуру `WNDCLASSEX` это осуществляется с помощью неё (по крайней мере у меня это так).

P.S.  про её составляющие: `hIcon` и `hIconSm`